# Cannot read data from newly uploaded Excel file

Tags: java, excel, file-upload

I'm working on a system where the users need to be able to upload an excel file to the server, then the system needs to process the excel file to load data into the XMPie uProduce system.

I already have it working to load CSV files into the system.  I can confirm that the excel files have been uploaded to the server successfully.  However, when my program then tries to access the excel file in order to read the data, it gets this error:

`The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.`

I am setting the filter as:

`select * from [Sheet1]`

I have also tried it as:

`select * from [filename.xls]`

Neither have worked.  Does anyone have any suggestions what the SQL filter should be for pulling data from a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying Excel sheet names in an SQL query via ADO or similar, you have to put a $ symbol at the end of the sheet name. Try:

`SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]`

More info [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819)

Comment: Thank you very much!  After struggling to search for exactly how to do this for so many hours, it's a great relief to me to come in this morning and find the answer waiting.

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

Writing an Excel query is as similar as writing a query in any other traditional data storage like SQL Server, Oracle, etc. However there are a few differences. First, you have to specify your sheet name instead of your table name. Next, you have to give starting and end cell references. Watch my following code carefully:

SELECT * FROM [users$A1:F500]

Here users is the spread sheet name.

Comment: Thank you, very much.  I spent so much time looking for this answer.